# One a:hover styling not working

Tags: css

This is my code:

```
.header li a:hover {
  color:black;  
  background-color:red;  
  text-decoration:none; 
  font-size:1.25em;
}
```

This is the website:

http://grantfranken.com

Before I added the `text-decoration` and `font-size` styles, the `color` and `background-color` styles were working. Once I added the other styles, they stopped working. How can I fix that? Does the order of styles matter?

Comment: Styles for `.header li a:link` and `:visited` are overriding the `:hover`

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/

Comment: yes the order of styles do matter, it is read from the top down.

Comment: line 20 is overriding hover styles, try either placing hover styles after it or change to .header li a:link:hover

Answer (score 1):

your problem is the order of `pseudo-classes` of `a`.

you have this:

```
.header li a:hover {color:black;  background-color:red;  text-decoration:none; font-size:1.25em;}

.header li a:link {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:visited {color:red;  background-color:black;}
```

instead you should have this:

```
.header li a:link {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:visited {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:hover {color:black;  background-color:red;  text-decoration:none; font-size:1.25em;}

.header li a:active {/* your CSS styles here */}
```

remember this:

**Link, Visited, Hover, Active

L, V, H, A

LoVe, HAte**

Answer (score 0):

You have the styles in the wrong order.

```
.header li a:hover {color:black;  background-color:red;  text-decoration:none; font-size:1.25em;}

.header li a:link {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:visited {color:red;  background-color:black;}
```

> `a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited` in the CSS definition in
>   order to be effective!! 
>   `a:active MUST come after`a:hover` in the CSS definition in order to be effective!!

So.

```
.header li a:link {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:visited {color:red;  background-color:black;}

.header li a:hover {color:black;  background-color:red;  text-decoration:none; font-size:1.25em;}
```